# How do I sort Data from backendless and Hide (Not Remove) Duplicates for Android?

Tags: android, sorting, android-studio, button, backendless

I am Creating An App that will allow users to select Drinks From a tablet with in the store. The Store Managers will be able to upload New Drinks from Backendless. The Goal is to have a button For Every Brand however I am unsure of how to stop from Duplicating a button For two Different Drinks. [image: How My Table Is set up]

Originally I was going to Attempt to sort them then Count them but then add the buttons to match but I do not know how have it only Count the Brand Once. 
I searched Through Backendless's API Documentation and I was unable to find what I needed.

```
     DataQueryBuilder queryBuilder = DataQueryBuilder.create();


          Backendless.Data.of( "Location_1" ).getObjectCount( queryBuilder,
                    new AsyncCallback<Integer>()
                    {
                     @Override
                 public void handleResponse( Integer integer )
                                {
                         Log.i( "MYAPP", "found Brands " + integer );

    }
     @Override
     public void handleFault( BackendlessFault backendlessFault )
                                {
   Log.i( "MYAPP", "error - " + backendlessFault.getMessage() );
                                }} );
```

Comment: So when the user clicks the button with the brand name you app displays a list of all the "Flavor"(s) for that particular brand?

Comment: yes, that is the case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `COUNT` aggregate function and group the results by the `Brand` name. The API is described in the doc at: https://backendless.com/docs/android/doc.html#data_count

Here's a sample code:

```
DataQueryBuilder dataQueryBuilder = DataQueryBuilder.create();
dataQueryBuilder.setProperties( "Count(objectId)", "Brand" );
dataQueryBuilder.setGroupBy( "Brand" );
Backendless.Data.of( "Brands" ).find( dataQueryBuilder, new AsyncCallback<List<Map>>()
{
  @Override
  public void handleResponse( List<Map> response )
  {
    Log.i( "MYAPP", response );
  }

  @Override
  public void handleFault( BackendlessFault fault )
  {
    Log.e( "MYAPP", fault.toString() ); 
  }
});
```

Comment: How would I then Display the brand as  Button? Everything that I tried comes up as NULL

Comment: That would be more of an Android UI question (which is not my forte). Try posting it to an Android discussion group and to make it easier to understand say that you get a collection of objects from the server, where each object is represented by java.util.Map. Then describe the issue of creating buttons from one of the properties in the received maps.